# How to describe nested object in Swagger API?

Tags: yaml, swagger

I am trying to describe below data structure for response of API endpoint using Swagger API.(Swagger description is shown below)
But, I get following error.
line `- smallpower` should be object.
May I know what is wrong?

**actual API return**

```
{
    "smallpower": [
        {
            "A": "A",
            "B": 11.9,
            "C": true,
            "D": "D"
        },
    {
            "A": "A",
            "B": 11.9,
            "C": true,
            "D": "D"
        },
    ],
    "oa": [
        {
            "A": "A",
            "B": 11.9,
            "C": true,
            "D": "D"
        },
    {
            "A": "A",
            "B": 11.9,
            "C": true,
            "D": "D"
        },
    ],
    "light": [
        {
            "A": "A",
            "B": 11.9,
            "C": true,
            "D": "D"
        },
    {
            "A": "A",
            "B": 11.9,
            "C": true,
            "D": "D"
        },
    ]
}
```

**Swagger API specification**

```
  responses:
    '200':
      description: successful operation
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              - smallpower:
                type: object
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/SmallPower'
              - oa:
                type: object
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/OA'
              - light:
                type: object
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/light'
```

**Updated according to Helen's comment**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax for `properties` where each property is an array of `$ref`'erenced schemas:

```yaml
            properties:
              smallpower:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/SmallPower'
              oa:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/OA'
              light:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/light'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is almost fixed. But I want value to be array of object rather than just object. Could you help me to fix this? I added current situation picture above